# Maximum value of a quantity

Tags: differentiation, calculus

While solving problems based on finding the maximum value of quantities such as maximum force or maximum power dissipated, I was told to differentiate the obtained expression and equate it to zero as it would give the point where the slope is zero that is the maxima or minima of a function. But I am not able to understand why we neglect the possibility that we could get the minimum value (minima) instead. In mathematics, we generally take the second derivative to check if we get the minima or the maxima, but we never do this in physics.

Comment: $\uparrow$ We who? Which page?

Comment: i mean generally i've seen my teachers doing it

Comment: ... *where the slope is zero* ...inflection points...???

Comment: @shivaadithya Teachers might do it if a) the premise is such that, one can infer through other means, that the extrema is a maxima, without calculating the second derivate. b) the calculation of the 2nd derivative might be trivial. But, whatever the reason, you are right that for a complete understanding, one should consider carefully if there is a possibility of it being a minima , and one of the ways to do it is obviously to calculate the 2nd derivative

Comment: In physics we are allowed to use reasoning that is not strictly algebraic to solve our problems. Usually, by knowing the very basics of what you qualitatively expect to happen in your system, you can argue that the function only has one extreme and it is a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're correct. It is possible that we get two(or more) values where the derivative is $0$, and maybe we should check using the second derivative.

For finding the maximum force or maximum power as you've mentioned, it can be quite straightforward to find the range and thus the maximum or minimum value as required. However, some good physics problems involve a situation/setting where only the maxima(or minima) makes sense, and thus the question would require finding only the one that made sense. Oftentimes, such details can give us a sense of direction to tackle the problem.

Based on my very limited experience, I believe that graphing the function gives us a better picture. Finding the maxima/minima is not a tough job once you've plotted the function nicely, and can tell us some "hidden" nice properties of the variation of that quantity-and we can try explaining those nice properties using principles of physics (now that we've seen it using math).

So no, we don't really "neglect" the possibility, it might just be that it does not make sense or is not important/required.

Comment: so graphs generally contains only a maxima or only a minima?

Comment: @shivaadithya No. Not at all necessarily. You may have no maxima/minima, or even multiple. For multiple maxima/minima, then you have consider which do you want, i.e. global maxima/minima or local (maxima/minima in a certain interval). 
Say you have to find the maximum velocity of a particle in two given time intervals-so you would consider the local maxima corresponding to each of the intervals. However, if asked the maximum velocity of a particle, then you would consider the global maxima. It is usually easier to see these multiple properties together when you have the graph.

Comment: I get it now... Thanks a lot